# In R, is there any reason why a data.frame object with just one column should be converted into a vector?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

Is there any reason why a data.frame object with just one column should be converted into a vector?

*Note*: I'm quite new to the world of R. Please correct me if my language is wrong or not clear.

Thank you.

Comment: An example may be useful, because a data frame should not be coerced to a vector just by virtue of having one column. The one column in the data frame (like other columns if the data frame had more than 1 column) will be a vector, though.
Added some code as an example: 
````r
data = data.frame(x = c("what", "am", "I?"))
class(data)
class(data$x)
````

Comment: Depends on the context. In general, a data.frame with only one column can be treated as a vector without converting...

Comment: If you extract a single column from a data frame, it is automatically converted to a vector. That feature is basically intended to be more convenient because the R developers assumed that users would be expecting a vector in that situation. Sometimes it can be problematic though. You can suppress with `df[,1,drop=FALSE]` to get a one column data frame.

Comment: @qdread's comment is right, that is by-design (though I refute that it is the expected response, I think it is inconsistent). However, this is `data.frame`-only; variants do not repeat this, compare `mtcars[,1]`, `tibble::tibble(mtcars)[,1]`, and `data.table::as.data.table(mtcars)[,1]`. In the first case, `mtcars[,1,drop=FALSE]` prevents this coersion. See [`?[`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html).

Comment: It's an intentionally "convenience" that I've never found convenient in 15 years of coding.